# how to select n rows

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

i have a database about several companies which include their name, price of share, %age change:

```
NAME           PRICE              % CHANGE
-------------------------------------------------
a              67                  11
b              23                  6
c              456                 5.89  
d              112                 23.98       
e              31                  17            
f              78                  3.09              
g              2678                12.56                   
h              357                 4.6
```

i want to select top 5 rows %age wise,means which hav maximum %age to be displayed at the top...n preceeding by jst 4 more value in desc. order...

OUTPUT SHOULD BE

```
NAME           PRICE              % CHANGE
-------------------------------------------------
d              112                 23.98   
e              31                  17            
g              2678                12.56  
a              67                  11   
b              23                  6
```

Answer (score 8):

### Using MySQL/Postgres:

```
  SELECT t.name,
         t.price,
         t.change
    FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY t.change DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

`LIMIT` clause:

- [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)
- [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html)

### Using SQL Server:

```
  SELECT TOP 5
         t.name,
         t.price,
         t.change
    FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY t.change DESC
```

`TOP` is [supported on SQL Server 2000+ at least](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

### Oracle:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT t.name,
               t.price,
               t.change
          FROM TABLE t
      ORDER BY t.change DESC) x
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

Oracle's [ROWNUM](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html)

Comment: I want the Oracle syntax too! :-)  Which, actually, is closest to ISO SQL 2008 (as ROW_NUMBER() is one of the ISO SQL “window functions”).

Comment: Updated to provide links to documentation.

Comment: Thanks :-)  I already upvoted you, so I can't do it once more.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding something... This is basic SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY change DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause isn't basic SQL - that syntax is only supported on MySQL and Postgres

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY change DESC LIMIT 5
```

**EDIT**: Note that `change`should be the name of the column that you listed as `% CHANGE`...

Answer (score 0):

Order by and limit
SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY change DESC LIMIT 5;

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 * from tblname order by change desc
```